# Can I generate a notification using Facebook API whenever someone changes his/her profile picture?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

How can I generate a notification on profile picture change on Facebook.
Here is the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cpicture&version=v2.1).

```
{
  "id": "727415489", 
  "name": "Fahad Uddin", 
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false, 
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/c3.0.50.50/p50x50/1653571_10152290086695490_673404407707634373_n.jpg?oh=bd5edc482c9197ec2aa08da7c277b346&oe=54BDDB0F&__gda__=1421798955_a7e01589caefd3d82881e50c768f0487"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1

The Realtime API lets you subscribe to changes of a User profile.